# Lua: Globally match for stuff of the form {{{parameter}}} or {{{parameter|default}}}, capturing "pattern" and "default", without overflow

Tags: lua, string-matching, lua-patterns, wikitext

I'm trying to use Lua pattern matching in a Wikipedia module to locate instances of Mediawiki parameter syntax (e.g. `{{{parameter1-a|defaultValue}}}` or `{{{parameter1-a|{{{alias1-a|defaultValue}}}}}}`) so they can be converted into Lua-compatible argument syntax. *(Yes, I am fully aware that using pattern matching for this is an unforgivable crime against humanity, but whatever.)*

So far, I have this relatively simple pattern, which works fine for the most part:

```lua
"{{{([^{}<>|]+)(|?([^{}|]*))}}}"
```

(Regex equivalent [hopefully], if you want to test on regex101: `/{{{([^{}<>|]+)(?:\|([^{}|]+)?)?}}}/g`)

However, this can't properly match anything in the "default" part that itself contains curly braces, so I can't include aliases for the parameter or template wikitext in the default. More specifically:

- The unmodified regex will, if given something like `{{{parameter|{{{alias|default}}}}}}`, just match/capture {{{parameter|**{{{`alias`|`default`}}}**}}}.
- Removing the curly brace restriction (`"{{{([^{}<>|]+)(|?([^{}|]*))}}}"`) will succeed with `{{{parameter|{{{alias}}}}}}`, yielding **{{{`parameter`|`{{{alias}}}`}}}** as intended, but with a default on the alias it'll give {{{parameter|**{{{`alias`|`default}}}`}}}**
- Just matching everything (`"{{{([^{}<>|]+)(|?(.*))}}}"`) works perfectly with one parameter, but with two it'll "spill" if the first has a default: `{{{parameter1|default}}} {{{parameter2}}}` will yield **{{{`parameter1`|`default}}} {{{parameter2`}}}**

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use case for Lua's special bracket matching pattern item `%b`! Using `%b{}`, you can match a pair of matching curly braces. By surrounding this with two curly braces on each side, you can match three pairs of curly braces.

Given your test cases:

```lua
local text = [[
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
{{{blarg}}}
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
{{{blarg|default}}}
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
{{{parameter1-a|{{{alias1-a|defaultValue}}}}}}
]]
```

and using the pattern `{{%b{}}}` in `gmatch`:

```lua
for match in text:gmatch"{{%b{}}}" do
    print(match)
end
```

you get

```
{{{blarg}}}
{{{blarg|default}}}
{{{parameter1-a|{{{alias1-a|defaultValue}}}}}}
```

as expected. You can then further process this parameter:

```lua
local content = match:sub(4, -4) -- cut off curly braces
local param, default = match:match"^([^|]+)|([^|]+)$"
if not param then param = content end -- no default
```

(I've simplified your pattern a bit here, this isn't exactly equivalent; it is more permissive)